# SharePoint 2013 CSOM Upload Doc and Change Column Values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I'd like to upload a document to a SharePoint 2013 document library and set value for three of the columns.

I'm running following C# code from a unit test within Visual Studio:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext($"{spRoot}/{spPathToFolder}"))
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, targetFileUrl, ms, true);

                var uploadedFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(targetFileUrl);
                var listItem = uploadedFile.ListItemAllFields;
                listItem["Title"] = "title";
                listItem["UPRN"] = "uprn";
                listItem["KeystoneDocType"] = "keystoneDocType";
                listItem.File.CheckIn("Added by BizTalk", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                listItem.Update();
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

The following path variables values are logged:

```
spRoot=[https://collaboration.xxx.com], spPathToFolder=[sites/HousingICTSolution/Technical]

targetFileUrl=[/sites/HousingICTSolution/Technical/AssetMgmtEfilesDemo/xxxLogo_190213115512.png]
```

The file gets uploaded ok (and I can view it when I click the link withing the SharePoint library) but no column values are set. Another problem is that executing the line "ctx.ExecuteQuery()" causes the following exception to be thrown:

```
        Message "The file AssetMgmtEfilesDemo/xxxLogo_190213115512.png has been modified by i:0#.w|xxx\\adm-tco05544 on 13 Feb 2019 11:59:35 -0000."    string
```

I am user "adm-tco05544". Can anyone suggest how to prevent the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before updating the file item fields, please firstly checkout and then update list fields value, finally check in the file, here is a working snippet for your reference:

```
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://sp/sites/dev");
        using (FileStream fs=new FileStream(@"C:\\Test.jpg",FileMode.Open))
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, "/sites/dev/MyDocLibraryName/Test.jpg", fs, true);
            var uploadedFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/MyDocLibraryName/Test.jpg");
            ctx.Load(uploadedFile);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                if (uploadedFile.CheckOutType==CheckOutType.None)
                {
                    uploadedFile.CheckOut();

                }

                    var listItem = uploadedFile.ListItemAllFields;
                    listItem["Title"] = "title";
                    listItem["UPRN"] = "uprn";
                    listItem["KeystoneDocType"] = "keystoneDocType";

                    listItem.Update();
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    listItem.File.CheckIn("Added by BizTalk", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();




        }
```

[image]

Comment: On executing the checkout, the following exception is raised: {"The file \"https://collaboration.leeds.gov.uk/sites/HousingICTSolution/Technical/AssetMgmtEfilesDemo/LeedsLogo_190215022009.png\" is checked out for editing by i:0#.w|leeds\\adm-tco05544."}

Comment: This means the file has been checked out, then remove uploadedFile.Checkout() function, and please make sure listItem.Update() before the file checkIn(). I will update the code snippet above, please check.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry_MSFT, that worked once I removed the CheckOut command.